# How to reshape dataframe if they have same index?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like

```
df= pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d'],index=[0,0,1,1])
```

```
   0
0  a
0  b
1  c
1  d
```

How can I reshape the dataframe based on index like below i.e

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],['c','d']],index=[0,1])
```

```
  0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

Comment: What do you need from me?

Comment: this wont work if I have multiple columns. This is very much similar to the other question.

Comment: I will try to put new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's use `set_index`, `groupby`, `cumcount`, and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)[0].unstack()
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

Comment: Character by character identical to me... except I put a space after the comma, pep standards and all (-:

Comment: you won't believe it - i had the same solution, but you were faster... ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir.

Comment: @Scott Boston can you try the solution for multiple columns. Im stuck now

Comment: @ScottBoston i made it a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467416/how-to-reshape-a-dataframe-if-they-have-similar-index-and-multiple-columns

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot` with `cumcount` :

```
a = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = pd.pivot(index=df.index, columns=a, values=df[0])
```

Comment: this wont work if I had multiple columns. Any improvements

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways

**1.**

```
In [490]: df.groupby(df.index)[0].agg(lambda x: list(x)).apply(pd.Series)
Out[490]:
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

**2.**

```
In [447]: df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.tolist()).str[0])
Out[447]:
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

**3.**

```
In [455]: df.assign(i=df.index, c=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).pivot('i', 'c', 0)
Out[455]:
c  0  1
i
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

to remove names

```
In [457]: (df.assign(i=df.index, c=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).pivot('i', 'c', 0)
           .rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1))
Out[457]:
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

Comment: Thank you John for letting me know of the options.

Comment: Im stuck when it comes to multiple columns.