# How to generate a new Pandas dataframe where I compress some rows into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am fairly new to pandas DataFrame but I have been watching tutorials and reading documentation about it and I cannot fully figure out a way to do what I want. I have a DataFrame indexed by time stamps and I want to bucket a certain period into a single row. Graphically:

```
    # start date of the series
start_date='20130101'
# range of dates
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=6)

# random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([["(1,1)","(1,2)"],
                   ["(2,1)","(2,2)"],
                   ["(3,1)","(3,2)"],
                   ["(4,1)","(4,2)"],
                   ["(5,1)","(5,2)"],
                   ["(6,1)","(6,2)"]], index=dates, columns=list('AB'))
print(df)
# range of bucketing periods, in this case I will get just three periods covering two days each
rng = pd.period_range(start_date, periods=3,freq='2D')
```

This results in

```
              A      B
2013-01-01  (1,1)  (1,2)
2013-01-02  (2,1)  (2,2)
2013-01-03  (3,1)  (3,2)
2013-01-04  (4,1)  (4,2)
2013-01-05  (5,1)  (5,2)
2013-01-06  (6,1)  (6,2)
```

What I would like to do is to generate now a new dataframe where I have the periods in `rng = pd.period_range(start_date, periods=3,freq='2D')` as indices and the rows corresponding to that period as consecutive columns:

```
              A      B      A1      B1
2013-01-01  (1,1)  (1,2)  (2,1)  (2,2)            
2013-01-03  (3,1)  (3,2)  (4,1)  (4,2)  
2013-01-05  (5,1)  (5,2)  (6,1)  (6,2)
```

Is there any method in the Api that I can use to do this?
I imagine I also need to generate new labels like A1,B1.

Also, after I thought a bit more, I can probably do with

```
              A      A1      B      B1
2013-01-01  (1,1)  (2,1)  (1,2)  (2,2)            
2013-01-03  (3,1)  (4,1)  (3,2)  (4,2)  
2013-01-05  (5,1)  (6,1)  (5,2)  (6,2)
```

Comment: How are the periods decided?

Comment: The periods are from the period range rng as defined above. I am taking it as a 2d period for this example.

Comment: I'm asking because what you want can be achieved through a simple reshape: `pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values, (-1, 4)))`

Comment: That's a way of doing it, thanks. However, I want to select based on the Timestamp and the periods I generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way is by converting the periods to `timestamp` and making a dataframe then concating them filling `NaN` with `ffill` method, and [reshape based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677788/how-to-reshape-dataframe-if-they-have-same-index) by setting the new timestamp column as index i.e

```
n = pd.DataFrame(rng.to_timestamp()).set_index(rng.to_timestamp())

result = pd.concat([df, n], axis=1).fillna(method='ffill').set_index(0)

result = result.set_index(result.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).unstack()
```

Output

```
                A             B       
                0      1      0      1
0                                     
2013-01-01  (1,1)  (2,1)  (1,2)  (2,2)
2013-01-03  (3,1)  (4,1)  (3,2)  (4,2)
2013-01-05  (5,1)  (6,1)  (5,2)  (6,2)
In [1024]:
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help @Paco