# Transposing each row data in to column data for each ID in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas datframe looks like this

```
Id   Length1 height1 Length2 height2
1     100     20       80     30
2      70     10       60     15
```

ALL Id's data need to be grouped for length/height of each measurement.

```
Id   0           1     2       3
1    100         20    70      10
2    80          30    60      15
```

How to transpose the rows in to columns and columns in to rows in dataframe

Comment: No pics please.  We need to copy data to try our answers.

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557). These images are not even of Pandas code, so please, post your Pandas code instead of Excel screenshots.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you do the same try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677788/how-to-reshape-dataframe-if-they-have-same-index

Comment: sorry i have pasted the data in a hurry.Will never repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Length1=[1, 2, 3],
    Height1=[4, 5, 6],
    Length2=[7, 8, 9],
    Height2=[0, 1, 2]
))['Length1 Height1 Length2 Height2'.split()]

df

   Length1  Height1  Length2  Height2
0        1        4        7        0
1        2        5        8        1
2        3        6        9        2
```

---

```
pd.DataFrame({n: g.values.ravel() for n, g in df.groupby(lambda x: x[-1], 1)}).T

   0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  4  2  5  3  6
2  7  0  8  1  9  2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[4,5,4],
                   'l1':[7,8,9],
                   'h1':[1,3,5],
                   'l2':[5,3,6],
                   'h2':[4,3,5]}, columns = ['id','l1','h1','l2', 'h2'])

print (df)
   id  l1  h1  l2  h2
0   4   7   1   5   4
1   5   8   3   3   3
2   4   9   5   6   5



df = df.set_index('id')
k = len(df.index)

a = df.values
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((a[:, :2].reshape(1, -1), a[:, 2:].reshape(1, -1))))
#create columns names by range
L = ['l', 'h']
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(x, y) for y in range(1, k+1) for x in L]
print (df)
   l1  h1  l2  h2  l3  h3
0   7   1   8   3   9   5
1   5   4   3   3   6   5
```