# How to reshape a multi-column dataframe by index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677788/how-to-reshape-dataframe-if-they-have-same-index?noredirect=1#comment79889384_45677788) . The solution works for only one column. How to improve the solution for multiple columns. i.e  If I have a dataframe like

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','z'],['d','b']],index=[0,0,1,1])
```

```
   0  1
0  a  b
0  b  c
1  c  z
1  d  b
```

How to reshape them like

```
  0   1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c 
1  c  z  d  b
```

If df is

```
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  z
1  d  b
```

Then

```
   0  1   2  3
0  a  b NaN  NaN
1  c  z   d  b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatten/ravel`

```
In [4401]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.flatten()))
Out[4401]:
   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c
1  c  z  d  b
```

Or, `stack`

```
In [4413]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.stack().values))
Out[4413]:
   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c
1  c  z  d  b
```

Also, with unequal indices

```
In [4435]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.values.ravel()).apply(pd.Series)
Out[4435]:
   0  1    2    3
0  a  b  NaN  NaN
1  c  z    d    b
```

Comment: Updated the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` + `pd.Series` + `np.reshape`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.reshape(-1, )))

   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c
1  c  z  d  b
```

---

Solution for unequal number of indices - call the `pd.DataFrame` constructor instead.

```
df

   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  z
1  d  b

df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: \
      pd.DataFrame(x.values.reshape(1, -1))).reset_index(drop=True)

   0  1    2    3
0  a  b  NaN  NaN
1  c  z    d    b
```

Comment: Why is it that the groupby return series when you have uneqal index repetition

Comment: @Bharathshetty Works now... I think.

Comment: Yeap it works. Got confused why series got reset_index(drop=True) later realized its dataframe

Comment: And you know why I got series?

Comment: @Bharathshetty My guess? It didn't know what to do with the unequal elements, so it reshaped it lengthwise. With the second solution, we are explicitly making it 2D, (by specifying the second dimension of size 1).

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.DataFrame({n: g.values.ravel() for n, g in df.groupby(level=0)}).T

   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c
1  c  z  d  b
```

---

This is all over the place and I'm too tired to make it pretty

```
v = df.values
cc = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().values
i0, r = pd.factorize(df.index.values)
n, m = v.shape
j0 = np.tile(np.arange(m), n)
j = np.arange(r.size * m).reshape(-1, m)[cc].ravel()
i = i0.repeat(m)

e = np.empty((r.size, m * r.size), dtype=object)

e[i, j] = v.ravel()

pd.DataFrame(e, r)

   0  1     2     3
0  a  b  None  None
1  c  z     d     b
```

Comment: Sir array must be same length is a requirement. So this wont work when I got unequal indices

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  Working on it

Comment: Ah, you took the loop out of apply here.

Comment: Sir `pd.DataFrame(df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).unstack().values)` also reshapes but index aint preserved. Can you do something about it

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).unstack()
df1.set_axis(labels=pd.np.arange(len(df1.columns)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  a  b  b  c
1  c  d  z  b
```

Output for df with NaN:

```
   0     1  2     3
0  a  None  b  None
1  c     d  z     b
```

Comment: set_axis is one of the few inplace operations in Pandas.  However, in the next release of Pandas, I think there is going to be an inplace parameter added to set_axis.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16994