# Pandas data reshaping, turn multiple rows with the same index but different values into many columns based on incidence

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I have the following table in pandas

```
user_id idaggregate_info    num_events  num_lark_convo_events   num_meals_logged    num_breakfasts  num_lunches num_dinners num_snacks  total_activity  sleep_duration  num_activity_events num_weights num_notifs  idusermission   completed   mission_delta
0   0   406 94  20  7   2   2   2   1   4456    47738   72  0   18  1426    0   NaT
1   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   7 days 10:04:28
2   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   NaT
3   2   2088    356 32  15  6   6   1   2   41598   184113  314 1   21  967 1   8 days 00:03:05
4   2   2088    356 32  15  6   6   1   2   41598   184113  314 1   21  967 1   NaT
```

Some user_ids have multiple lines that are identical except for their different mission_delta values. How do I transform this into one line for each id, with a columns named "mission_delta_1", "mission_delta_2" (the number of them vary, it could be 1 per user_id to maybe 5 per user_id so naming has to be iterative_ etc so output would be:

```
user_id idaggregate_info    num_events  num_lark_convo_events   num_meals_logged    num_breakfasts  num_lunches num_dinners num_snacks  total_activity  sleep_duration  num_activity_events num_weights num_notifs  idusermission   completed   mission_delta_1 mission_delta_2
0   0   406 94  20  7   2   2   2   1   4456    47738   72  0   18  1426    0   NaT
1   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   7 days 10:04:28  NaT
2   2   2088    356 32  15  6   6   1   2   41598   184113  314 1   21  967 1   8 days 00:03:05     NaT
```

[Not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467416/how-to-reshape-a-multi-column-dataframe-by-index) as those address exploding all columns, there is just one that needs to be unstacked. The solutions offered in the duplicate link fail:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.flatten()))
```

produces the same df as the original with different labels

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
    0   0   406 94  20  7   2   2   2   1   4456    47738   72  0   18  1426    0   NaT
    1   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   7 days 10:04:28
    2   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   NaT
    3   2   2088    356 32  15  6   6   1   2   41598   184113  314 1   21  967 1   8 days 00:03:05
```

The next options:

```
result2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.stack().values))
```

produces:

```
0     0         0
  1       406
  2        94
  3        20
  4         7
```

and

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.values.ravel()).apply(pd.Series)
```

produces the original dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
    0   0   406 94  20  7   2   2   2   1   4456    47738   72  0   18  1426    0   NaT
    1   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   7 days 10:04:28
    2   1   1247    121 48  26  8   7   2   9   48695   37560   53  14  48  1379    1   NaT
    3   2   2088    356 32  15  6   6   1   2   41598   184113  314 1   21  967 1   8 days 00:03:05
```

In essence, I want to turn a df:

```
id    mission_delta
0     NaT
1     1 day
1     2 days
1     1 day
2     5 days
2      NaT
```

into

```
id    mission_delta1  mission_delta_2 mission_delta_3
0     NaT     NaT        NaT
1     1 day   2 days    1 day
2     5 days   NaT      NaT
```

Comment: Edited to update how the linked answer doesn't fully address my question.

Comment: Hi Heather, please upvote as well if the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this;

```
grp = df.groupby('id')
df_res = grp['mission_delta'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().fillna('NaT')
df_res = df_res.rename(columns={i: 'mission_delta_{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(len(df_res))})

print(df_res)

   mission_delta_1 mission_delta_2 mission_delta_3
id                                                
0              NaT             NaT             NaT
1            1 day          2 days           1 day
2           5 days             NaT             NaT
```